# Teradata Get Week Number using SQL Code

Tags: sql, date, teradata, week-number

I wish to get the week number from a date in teradata
I can see there are solutions to use the Sys Calendar Table but i would like to use code to get the week number

Week 28 for example is the 6th to the 12th of July inclusive

I have found this [code](https://forums.teradata.com/forum/database/getting-week-of-the-year-from-a-date) which works fine when you put DATE instead of cdate

```
SELECT 
((cdate - ((EXTRACT(YEAR FROM cdate) - 1900) * 10000 + 0101 (DATE))) -     ((cdate - DATE '0001-01-07') MOD 7)  + 13) / 7
```

My date is in the format MM/DD/YY and when i run it i get the error message

```
SELECT ((06/29/15 - ((EXTRACT(YEAR FROM 06/29/15) - 1900) * 10000 + 0101     (DATE))) - ((06/29/15 - DATE '0001-01-07') MOD 7)  + 13) / 7
```

"User cannot perform that operation on DATE"

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A date format is only used for casting to a string (= display), but the datatype DATE has no format, it's an integer.

`06/29/15` is not a date, it's a calculation based on integers `6 / 29 / 15` which results in an integer zero.

Dates are always specified in ISO format: `DATE '2015-06-29'`:

```
((DATE '2015-06-29' - ((EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE '2015-06-29') - 1900) * 10000 + 0101     (DATE))) - ((DATE '2015-06-29' - DATE '0001-01-07') MOD 7)  + 13) / 7
```

But your week seems to be based on the international standard and this calculation will not return the correct number for the last days of a year, e.g. Wednesday 2014-12-31 will be week 53 while it should be week 1 in ISO. If ISO weeks are needed you better use

```
WEEKNUMBER_OF_YEAR (DATE '2015-06-29', 'ISO') -- integer
or
TO_CHAR(DATE '2015-06-29', 'iw')  -- string
```

Edit:

Those functions were added in TD14, before you can use following code for ISO week/year:

```
REPLACE FUNCTION iso_week(cdate DATE)
RETURNS INT
SPECIFIC iso_week_date
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
CONTAINS SQL
DETERMINISTIC
COLLATION INVOKER
INLINE TYPE 1
RETURN 
                      (((cDate - ((cdate - DATE '0001-01-01') MOD 7) + 5)
  - ((EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (cDate - ((cdate - DATE '0001-01-01') MOD 7) + 5)) - 1900) * 10000 + 0101 (DATE))) / 7) + 1  (FORMAT '99')
;

REPLACE FUNCTION iso_year(cdate DATE)
RETURNS INT
SPECIFIC iso_year_date
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
CONTAINS SQL
DETERMINISTIC
COLLATION INVOKER
INLINE TYPE 1
RETURN  
  EXTRACT (YEAR FROM (cDate - (((cdate - DATE '0001-01-01') MOD 7) + 1) + 4)) (FORMAT '9999')
;
```

If you're not allowed to create SQL UDFs you can simply cut&paste the calculation.

Comment: Hi @dnoeth, thanks for your quick reply...When i run both scripts i get the error message: 3707 Syntax Error, expected something like ')' between 'dAtE' keyword and the string '2'

Comment: I just tested it, works fine for me as-is. How do you submit it?

Comment: Submitted like below

SELECT WEEKNUMBER_OF_YEAR (DATE '2015-06-29', 'ISO')

SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE '2015-06-29', 'iw')

Comment: That seems to be the problem...We are still on 13.10

Comment: @JohnSmith: Added an ISO calculation for TD13.10 :-)

Comment: Thank you @dnoeth, this was above and beyond what i was looking for. Have a nice day

Comment: @dnoeth, specifying column name in the function WEEKNUMBER_OF_YEAR() is not working... 
Can you please suggest any alternate solution for this ?

Comment: @Aditya: *is not working*: is there an error message? What's your Teradata release?

Comment: @dnoeth, sorry, my mistake! The query is working perfectly, don't know what went wrong when I tried it earlier. Now I used following query & it worked, thanks :)   SEL WEEKNUMBER_OF_YEAR (Calendar_Date) FROM Sys_Calendar.CALENDAR